# what is the meaning of "In an average week last year" in this paragraph?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> In an average week last year, three people were killed while defending
>   their land and the environment from industries such as mining, logging
>   and agribusiness, the report said.

I think in the above paragraph the meaning of "In an average week last year..." is:  "every week 3 people killed in average(So in the whole year almost 156 people)". Is my guess true?

Comment: That's what it means, but your version is more grammmatical as "every week 3 people were killed ***on*** average." It's "**in** an average week", but "**on** average".

Comment: "Almost 156" means less than 156, you should use "about" e.g. Every week 3 people **were** killed **on** average. (So about 156 people in the whole year).

Comment: Thank you very much.